# $X_{n+1} = \phi_{n+1}(X_n, Y_{n+1})$ yields a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $(E, \mathcal B(E))$ be a Polish space and $X_0$ be a random variable with values in $E$.
>
> Let  $Y_0,Y_1,\ldots$ be independent random variables with values in $(F,\mathcal F)$ and assume that $X_0$ is independent from the $Y_i$'s.
>
> Let $\phi_n:E\times F \to E$ be a sequence of measurable functions.
>
> Define inductively $X_{n+1} = \phi_{n+1}(X_n, Y_{n+1})$. Prove that $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain.

I'm using the following definition of Markov chain: $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain if $$\forall n\geq 1,\forall A\in \mathcal B(E),P(X_{n+1}\in A |X_n, \ldots, X_0)=P(X_{n+1}\in A |X_n)$$

I have noticed that each $X_n$ is a measurable function of $X_0,Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$, hence $X_n$ is independent of $Y_{n+1}$

I have tried using regular conditional distribution: $$P(X_{n+1}\in A |X_n=x_n, \ldots, X_0=x_0) = P(\phi_{n+1}(x_n,Y_{n+1})\in A|X_n=x_n, \ldots, X_0=x_0) $$

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: $$P(X_{n+1}\in A \mid X_n, \ldots, X_0)=g_{n+1}(X_n,A)\qquad g_{n+1}(x,A)=P(\phi_{n+1}(x,Y_0)\in A)$$

Comment: @Did Is there an easier way than using the lemma "if $X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable and $Y$ is independent from $\mathcal G$, then $E(\phi(X,Y)|\mathcal  G) = E(\phi(\cdot, Y))\circ X$" ? I find it quite technical to prove.

Comment: And yet, if you are into the mathematics of Markov chains, you better get acquainted with it once and for all.